# SMPlayer subtitled stopped showing

Tags: 14.04, smplayer

I was watching a video in smplayer (in ubuntu 14.04) and the subtitles suddenly stopped showing. I don't know what happened , but now no video is showing any subtitles.
I tried uninstalling and installing SMPlayer again but it didn't help.
Please help me solve this.

Comment: try pressing v, or unchick the costume subtitle

Comment: I tried to delete the ini file - to reset to defaults and even reinstalled the player , so it's a bit strange ... but your suggestion helped. Thanks a lot

Comment: so it's working now??

Comment: yeah , it's working

Comment: i'll make it a question, vote it up, and mark it as the right answer :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have ever had the subtitles hidden or used a custom subtitle settings

Try pressing <kbd>v</kbd> If it didn't show

Un-check the custom subtitle in the right click menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to uncheck/check "Use [ASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubStation_Alpha#Advanced_SubStation_Alpha) library" in Preferences.